# Dynamics CRM - Do not Track emails sent between team members

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have automatic creation and updation rule which is tied to a shared mailbox, whenever an email arrives at the shared mailbox from the customer, it is tracked in dynamics and a case is created for it.

Now when a reply email is sent or forwarded between users within the team, it is also getting tracked which the users do not want as those emails can have confidential information.

They only want emails received and sent to customers to be tracked. is there a way i can achieve this? 
one option is they can untrack the email from outlook app however asking them to do it for every email is quite a time consuming task.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated